# Google Chrome extension installed popup

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

While installing the Google extensions form chrome web store it shows some popup like "Google Chrome extension is now installed".

I want similarly, while login I need to show the login popup.

Please suggest me on this.

[image]

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/29331302/32453

Answer (score 4):

You can create either a [browser action](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/browserAction.html) or a [page action](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/pageAction.html) popup. You can change popup html dynamically to make it look completely different depending on the situation but you can't open it programmatically ([desktop notifications](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/notifications.html) could be used for alerts).