# Chrome Extension installation popup

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popupwindow

When an extension is installed in chrome, a popup comes up which says [Extension_name] has been added to chrome.

This is the default popup having extension icon and some message. I want to modify this popup data. is there any api which we can use to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API, but you can use [onInstalled event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled) to open new tab with your own description.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Deliaz's answer, you can create either a [browser action](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/browserAction.html) or a [page action](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/pageAction.html) popup. You can [change popup html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756338/google-chrome-extension-installed-popup) dynamically to make it look completely different depending on the situation but you can't open it programmatically ([desktop notifications](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/notifications.html) could be used for alerts).

Here's another [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331302/chrome-extension-popup-installation) which might also help.